# subir múltiples archivo con php

Tags: php, php7, php5

tengo la siguiente duda, actualmente hice el código de subir únicamente un archivo a la vez, y lo sube correctamente (lo mueve de la carpeta temporal a su respectiva carpeta según el `ID` e inserta la información a la base de datos) este es el código.

input:

```
<input class="form-control" multiple type="file" id="archivo_acta" name="archivo_acta[]" accept="<?php echo $aceptados['Valor']; ?>">
```

código PHP:

```
 $directorio = "../archivos/archivoactas/$id_registro/";
        if (!is_dir($directorio)) {
            mkdir($directorio, 0755, true);
        }
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo_acta']['tmp_name'], $directorio . $_FILES['archivo_acta']['name'])) {
            $url = $directorio;
            $nombrearchivo =$_FILES['archivo_acta']['name'];
            $formato = pathinfo($nombrearchivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
            $url_resultado = "se subio correctamente";
        } else {
            $respuesta = array(
                'respuesta' => error_get_last()
            );
        }
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_acta_recursos(id_acta, url, fecha_carga, redactor,nombre,formato) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
        $stmt->bind_param("ississ", $id_registro,$url,$hoy,$redactor,$nombrearchivo,$formato);
        $stmt->execute();
```

mi pregunta es como mover los archivos de la carpeta temporal a su carpeta e insertar la información a la base de datos SIENDO MULTIPLES ARCHIVOS (como dije anteriormente un solo archivo lo sube sin problemas).

estuve intentando contar los archivos y meter el código en un for.. pero no hace nada ni los inserta la BBDD ni los mueve a su carpeta,si alguien me puede sacar de mi error, adjuntare el mismo código que anteriormente ya adjunte pero con la diferencia que tiene el for y su contador de archivos que estoy adjuntando.

```
    $directorio = "../archivos/archivoactas/$id_registro/";
     $cantidad= count($_FILES["archivo_acta"]["tmp_name"]);  //aqui contabilizo los archivos 
            if (!is_dir($directorio)) {
                mkdir($directorio, 0755, true);
            }

for ($i=0; $i<$cantidad; $i++){  //apertura FOR
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo_acta']['tmp_name'], $directorio . $_FILES['archivo_acta']['name'])) {
                $url = $directorio;
                $nombrearchivo =$_FILES['archivo_acta']['name'];
                $formato = pathinfo($nombrearchivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  
                $url_resultado = "se subio correctamente";
            } else {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => error_get_last()
                );
            }
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_acta_recursos(id_acta, url, fecha_carga, redactor,nombre,formato) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
            $stmt->bind_param("ississ", $id_registro,$url,$hoy,$redactor,$nombrearchivo,$formato);
            $stmt->execute();

} //cierre FOR
```

para estos datos tambien utilizo AJAX:

```
$('#editar-actas-archivo').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var datos = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: datos,
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var resultado = data;
                if (resultado.respuesta == 'exito') {
                    swal({
                        title: "Correcto", text: "Se guardo el borrador correctamente!", type:
                            "success"
                    }).then(function () {
                        location.href = "../Vistas/actas_pendientes_vista.php";
                    }
                    );
                } else {
                    swal(
                        'Error',
                        'Hubo un error!',
                        'error'
                    )
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

por favor si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradecería

Comment: Allí tienes que usar un `foreach`, la cuestión esta en la inserción, se que hay distintas formas de hacer esto pero, pensare en algo conveniente para ti, ya que colocar una inserción por ciclo no lo es, lo ideal es una inserción múltiple en una sola conexión

Comment: mucha gracias le agradecería si me ayuda, si eso estuve viendo lo de la inserción allí me lo complica

Comment: Por cierto, una pequeña observación, necesitas agregar el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` a tu formulario

Comment: si ya lo tiene, es que archivo por separado ya lo inserta y lo mueve, sin ese atributo no guardara ni uno

Comment: Perfecto..!! ya tengo una solución, en un momento agrego una respuesta ;)

Comment: huy enserio pues muchas gracias B) espero tu respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muy bien, para complementar lo dicho en el comentario, la solución ha tu consulta es la siguiente:

Como estos datos se envían con **ajax** y estas usando *jQuery*, deben enviarse de la siguiente manera:

```js
$('#editar-actas-archivo').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
   
        // Ojo acá, creamos un FormData y adjuntamos los archivos
        var datos = new FormData();
        datos.append('archivo_acta', $('#archivo_acta')[0].files);

        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: datos,
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
            processData: false,
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            // ... Aquí el resto de tu lógica javascript
```

Y para poder almacenar tus múltiple archivos y ademas insertar su información en la **base de datos**, debes hacer lo siguiente

```php
$directorio = "../archivos/archivoactas/$id_registro/";
$query = null;
$insert = [];

// Contamos los archivos
$cantidad= count($_FILES['archivo_acta']['name']);

// De no existir, creamos el directorio
if (!is_dir($directorio)) {
  mkdir($directorio, 0755, true);
}

// Guardamos cada archivo, en el directorio antes creado
// Si es que existen archivos
if($cantidad){
  
  foreach($_FILES['archivo_acta']['name'] as $index => $value){

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo_acta']['tmp_name'][$index], $directorio . $value);

    // Creamos un string de consulta único para este archivo
    $step = '(' . $id_registro . ',"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($directorio) . '",' . $hoy . ',"' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($redactor) . '","' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($value) . '","' . $mysqli->real_escape_string($_FILES['archivo_acta']['type'][$index]) . '")';
    array_push($insert, $step); 

  }

  // Creamos una consulta única, para insertar todos los registros en una sola conexión  
  $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_acta_recursos(id_acta, url, fecha_carga, redactor,nombre,formato) VALUES " . implode(', ', $insert);

  // La ejecutamos ;)
  $mysqli->query($query);

}
```

Esto ejecutara una sola consulta a tu base de datos para insertar todos los registros, sin necesidad de ejecutar una por ciclo dentro del `foreach`

Suponiendo que `$id_registro` y `$hoy` son valores que no necesitan ser escapados, de lo contrario deberías hacerlo con `real_escape_string()`

Te adjunto también la documentación de la función [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode) la cual use para unir el array en un string de consulta única.

Espero haberte ayudado :) mucha suerte

Comment: mueve los archivos pero no hace el insert :(

Comment: ¿Que error te da? a mi me funciono perfecto @ChristianSauceda

Comment: no ningún error, solo que no hacer el insert si selecciono tres archivos y voy a ver a la carpeta allí están, pero si voy a la BBDD no hay nada

Comment: Si no te da algún error en `$mysqli->errno` tu problema podría radicar en, la conexión a la base de datos o  tienes que cambiar el máximo de inserciones por consulta en la variable global de **MySQL** `max_allowed_packet`

Comment: @ChristianSauceda y creo que eso ultimo debería arrojar igualmente un error SQL

Comment: es que en otra sección del sistema hago inserciones de 'participantes' y a veces son hasta 60 participantes y hace las inserciones de cada uno

Comment: Me parece muy extraño que no arroje algún **error SQL**, tu problema parece venir de otro lado

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127458/discussion-between-josbert-and-christian-sauceda).

Comment: @ChristianSauceda ya edite, adicionando el paso necesario con el **ajax**

Comment: probare :D haber que tal